# Расположить начало блока на уровне контейнера

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Верстая сайт не могу выполнить выравнивание блока..

У меня есть блок в контейнере который не должен выходить за его рамку. Но блок ниже, начало его начинается на уровне контейнера но конец доходит до конца самого экрана устройства, а не самого контейнера.

Как мне вычислять тот отступ чтобы блок ниже `.another-block`

```css
.another-block {
  /*Я не знаю как тут вычислить отступ*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="block"> Элементы этого блока не должны выходить за рамки контейнера, как бы сильно я этого не хотел
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-block">
    Начало данного элемента должна начинаться с уровня контейнера, но конец должен быть, аж до конца самого экрана устройства
  </div>
</section>
```

Вот примерно следующий результат я хочу чтобы было у меня, но как сделать, не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Блоки автоматически будут выравниваться при изменении размера сайта, сохраняя своё местоположение. Вам лишь нужно оперировать `max-width` в зависимости от размера контентной области Вашего шаблона по которому делаете, изменяя размеры блока! (можете задавать фиксированный)

```css
.cont {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}

.block--red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.block--right {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="block"> 
      <h1>CONTENT</h1>
      <p>Элементы этого блока не должны выходить за рамки контейнера, как бы сильно я этого не хотел</p>
    </div>
    <div class=" block block--red block--right">
      <h1>CONTENT 2</h1>
      <p>Начало данного элемента должна начинаться с уровня контейнера, но конец должен быть, аж до конца самого экрана устройства</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

**UPD** вот с использование чисто бутстрапа. Но нужно заменять `container` на `container-fluid` иначе не получится. Обычный контейнер имеет отступ справа и слева и авто `margin`. Вы не сможете прижать элемент к правому краю не правя стили данного контейнера предоставляемый фреймворком! И Ваш `another-block` нужно запихнуть внутрь контейнера иначе они оба не будут отсчитываться от общей точки!

```css
.block {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}

.block--red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6 block"> 
        <h1>CONTENT</h1>
        <p>Элементы этого блока не должны выходить за рамки контейнера, как бы сильно я этого не хотел</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-9 block block--red"> 
        <h1>CONTENT</h1>
        <p>Элементы этого блока не должны выходить за рамки контейнера, как бы сильно я этого не хотел</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: Дело в том что я использую контейнер от бутстрепа, и мне было бы удобно выровнить его по его показателям, а не переверстывать все с 0 используя кастомный контейнер, как сделали вы в данном примере

Comment: @E1mir извиняюсь что долго, был занят. Добавил примеры на бутстрапе с объяснениями!

Comment: Прикольно, довольно хорошое решение) Да я работал также с fluid контейнером но добиться результата которого хотел не мог, но благодаря твоему ответу, я понял что да как)

Comment: @E1mir рад помочь :)